# Return json from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am  returning my first row from DB in this way

```
     const myobj = Post.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);
```

but when I try to define values to my array it is returning: [{"id":1}]

```
    app.get("/api/solutions", (req, res) => {
        const myobj = Post.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);
        const solutions = [
          {
              id: 1,
              title: myobj.title,
              subTitle: myobj.slogan,
              description: myobj.description
          },
        ]
        res.json(solutions);
     });
    const port = 5000;
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why `{_id: -1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many things in the Node universe, Mongoose requests are asynchronous. You are not waiting for the database to return its result. You need to `await` it.

Also, `.find()` returns an array. `.find().limit(1)` will return an array of 1 element. You want to use `.findOne()` which returns one document.

```
app.get("/api/solutions", async (req, res) => { // <-- add async

        const myobj = await Post // await Mongoose
                          .findOne() // Replace find().limit(1) with .findOne()
                          .sort({_id:-1}) // I don't think this is useful
                          .exec(); // add .exec()

        const solutions = [
          {
              id: 1,
              title: myobj.title,
              subTitle: myobj.slogan,
              description: myobj.description
          },
        ]
        res.json(solutions);
});

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: What if you `console.log(myobj)` ? What's the output?

Comment: it still returning  [{"id":1}]

Comment: consol.log return [
   {
 _id: 5e8f0eee09610c08dc2cfc12,
   title: 'my title',
 slogan: 'my slogan',
    description: 'my description',
   __v: 0
   }
]

Comment: but when I enter "/api/solutions" I still see  [{"id":1}]

Comment: Aaaaaaaah, I know, you're using `find()`, which returns an array, not `findOne()`, which returns one document. That's what you want. Answer updated